# Why is my answer always coming out positive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My answer is always 3, but the correct answer is negative 3. [image]

What I do is multiply everything by 10 because the common factor between all THREE components is 10.

Then I cancel the 10 with the denominator, then expand.

I end up with x = 3

Why ??

Comment: please write your whole calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere along the way you're making some sign error; without being able to see your work it's a little hard to say. But to go along with what you're describing, you end up with:
$$
2(x + 3) + 20 = 5(x + 7)
$$
or simplifying this, we find
$$
2x + 26 = 5x + 35
$$
If we now collect terms (move the $x$s to the right, and the integers to the left), we get
$$
26 - 35 =  5x - 2x
$$
or
$$
-9 = 3x
$$
and hence $x = -3$ as desired.

Comment: I put 9 instead of -9 in the last step because I have autism